# Animate navigation bar with view during push transition in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm using the iOS 7 transition API in for some custom transitions. I've got a great transition going, but have problems with the navbar. I want the navigation bar to act as part of the view, so there is a clear line/shadow going the entire vertical length of the screen. (Such as the Reeder app, from this screenshot)

[image]

In my view however, the line on the left side of the top view does not extend all the way to the top of the navigation bar.

[image]

Just a sample app, so the view stack is generic, and using just a standard UINavigationController.